# Account not provisioned to user using RBAC in oim12c

Tags: oracle12c, rbac, oracle11gr2, identity-management, oim

I have created a role and access policy (has app instance) assigned to the role.
when i create a user , role is assigned but no resource added to user account.

I ran catalogue as well evaluate user policy schedulers.Resource not updated in user account

Same worked in OIM11gR2Ps3 but not in 12c.

Kindly help.

Comment: did you check if there was any error in the logs while running EvaluateUserPolicies ? Also make sure the flag policy_eval_needed=1 is set in DB table user_provisioning_attrs, while policy_eval_in_progress=0

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev I cudnt find any errors in logs. And I have made chandes in DB as well . Still user is not provisioined .

Comment: do you check both -diagnostic and .out log files? Usually in .out you should be able to find the traces for User Evaluate Policies task running to double check for any errors or exceptions

Comment: How many resources are there in the access policy?Do check for any deadlock scenarios between the resources in different access policy.

Comment: @PriyaSharma i have only one resource assigned to access policy.

Comment: Can you check if there is an account in the OIU associated with the user for the resource and that the app instance key is assigned?

Comment: @BerkleyLamb I could see the user in usr table nut not in OIU table.

Comment: @Sairu Is the user disabled or not active by chance? (Maybe has a future start date)

Comment: Is it happening for single user or multiple users? Is it specific to application instance?